# Flickr Authentication in Java

Tags: java, oauth, flickr, flickrj

I am going to download geotagged_flickr images for a specific area!
I already got some information from flickr, but they did not authentication!
This time I need authentication!and this [link as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226956/flickr-authentication-with-oauth)
,but I read a lot, but I do not know how it works and what should I do?

Comment: did you get your apikey and secret?

Comment: yes, I got secret and apikey from Flickr